# Shell Scription: How to load some variables in multiple files

Tags: shell

**Situation:**
I am writing some Shell Scripts in CentOS 5.9. Suppose that I have following files in my folder:

- script.sh
- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt

This script is working with these text files. These text files are configuration files of certain program.

**Problem:**
How can I have some variables within these text files? I need to change the values just in script.sh. How can I do that in easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be an approach:

let's have in your `file1.txt` the following:

```
MY_VAR=23
```

then in your script you can have:

```
. /path/of/file.txt
```

so when you execute the script, `MY_VAR` will be directly accessible as a var.

---

In general, if you have a file with information like:

```
 VAR=value
```

these variables can be loaded in a script by having

```
. file
```

Comment: Sorry, I need reverse. I need to assign value in script and write them to the files. But what you said is also great. Probably I need it as well in near future.

Comment: Oh, I did understand it the other way round. This can help you: http://superuser.com/questions/235738/how-do-i-substitute-environment-variables-when-i-ouput-a-file